# Awarded bounty disappears after voting

Tags: bug, bounties, android-app

When I use the mobile app to vote for an answer that was awarded a bounty,  the bounty is no longer shown until I reload the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: the bounty indicator will persist even after the post is refreshed due to user voting on it.